# About C# object scope

Tags: c#, object, scope

So I've created a class and instantiate an object in the main window. Then, when I'm trying to use that object in a button within the same window, I don't know how to indicate the context for this object. I know this is a very basic question, but I'm learning and haven't been able to figure it out just yet.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DeltaMotor M2 = new DeltaMotor();
    M2.Card.Set8255();  
    M2.Stop();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    M2.Move(1); // this can't find M2 within the context
}
```

I know this is basic, but help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no such thing as "object scope". You're talking about the scope of local variables vs class fields.

Comment: Ed is correct. To clarify further: objects have *lifetimes*; this is a run-time concept. *Named things* have *scope*; scope is defined as *the portion of the text of the program in which the name can be used without qualification*. Scope is a compile-time concept; it is one of the mechanisms the compiler uses to determine what a name refers to.

Comment: Also, now would be a good day to get in the habit of using C# naming conventions. Locals and fields should be `camelCased`; properties and methods should be `PascalCased`. So your `M2` should be `m2` if a local or field, and `M2` if a property. However, `M2` is probably also a poor name choice because it is hard to read it and know what it is without context.

Comment: These are all great clarifications,  good comments and suggestions. I didn't know about the naming conventions, I will take a deeper look into that, and make sure I do everything right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As you've discovered, the `M2` object is not in scope inside the click handler, because it is a *local variable* inside the `MainWindow` constructor.

You can make `M2` an *instance variable* of the class, and access it from both methods, along the lines of:

```
private DeltaMotor M2;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    M2 = new DeltaMotor();
    M2.Card.Set8255();  
    M2.Stop();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    M2.Move(1);
}
```

Comment: To be precise, it's the MainWindow *constructor*.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to be accessible within this one class, then

```
private DeltaMotor M2;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    M2 = new DeltaMotor();
    M2.Card.Set8255();  
    M2.Stop();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    M2.Move(1); // this can't find M2 within the context
}
```

Will work quite nicely. For further learning, here's a Microsoft reference on variable and method scope:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Which will be useful if you ever what to access M2 in another class. Hope that helps you get started!

Answer (score 0):

You could declare `M2` as a class property:

```
private DeltaMotor M2 { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    M2 = new DeltaMotor();
    M2.Card.Set8255();  
    M2.Stop();
}
```

and then access it from whatever method you want:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    M2.Move(1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance member of `DeltaMotor` at the class level.

```
private DeltaMotor _m2;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _m2 = new DeltaMotor();
    _m2.Card.Set8255();  
    _m2.Stop();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _m2.Move(1);
}
```